# Polymer use Normal DOM, not Shadow DOM

Tags: dom, polymer, shadow-dom

Is there a way in polymer to create a component and NOT use the Shadow DOM?

I want the component in the Normal DOM, thus affected by all css like this:

```
<my-component>
  <p>Some text</p>
</my-component>
```

And NOT have it put its content in the Shadow DOM like this:

```
<my-component>
  #shadow-root
    <p>Some text</p>
</my-component>
```

Comment: Three is the global setting to enable shadow DOM https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings (default shady DOM)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is if there is a way to NOT use the Shadow DOM. Updated the question for clarity. This question may be somewhat obsolete if it's possible to use shared styles: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules

Comment: By default Polymer does **NOT** use shadow DOM.

Comment: But the shady DOM polyfill/shim (which is the default) will emulate the shadow DOM right so any styles I include in the head tag won't be applied or?

Comment: Shady DOM doesn't polyfill everything. Actually it doesn't polyfill much. Shady DOM requires you to use specific things like the Polymer DOM api to get used. If you enable shadow DOM then the polyfills try to polyfill as much as possible on browsers that don't have native shadow DOM support. For example if you don't use `<style is="custom-style">` but instead just `<style>` (in `<head>`), no shimming/polyfilling is done and the styles ignore component boundaries entirely.

Comment: Okey I see now that using the setting `dom: 'shady'` will actually create all components in the normal dom. Wonder if it's recommended to assume that components have the encapsulation of the shadow dom and use shared styles instead.

Comment: I didn't use Polymer recently. While I used it `shady` was default. Do you now have to set it explicitly (is `shadow` now the default)? I'd use shared styles. When shadow DOM is supported in all browsers natively switching to shadow DOM will work without or at least without much additional work.

Comment: `shady` is still the default (it won't be in the future) but I was in their _app-drawer-template_ where they had set `shadow` explicitly. Yea that probably makes sense. I'm adding polymer to an existing project and making it a single page app so will start with shady and gradually move over to shadow. Think that should work. Thanks for the help.